# Alter column [TIME] time just not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having headaches over this altering the time column to a Time data type to create a date/time stamp in another column. I have the date to a date datatype but just can not get this time right.

I have looked for everything in the column to why this query:

```
ALTER TABLE #TEMP ALTER COLUMN [TIME] TIME
```

would fail and give me the error:

```
 Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 72
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I have looked for `nulls`, for `''`, for `WHERE ISNUMERIC([TIME]) = 1` 
I have even updated the table to take out Newline Chars:

```
UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = REPLACE(REPLACE([TIME], CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') FROM #TEMP
```

I just don't know what else to do. The Date type of `[TIME]` is `nvarchar(MAX)` at the moment and just nee it to time Data Type so I can combine the `[DATE]` with `[TIME]` and create the `[DateTimeStamp]`

Does anyone have any other ideas on why it wont do it?

Comment: I would recommend just using a single timestamp rather than separate columns for the date and time.  Please post your full table definition.

Comment: Show sample data for that column

Comment: The data in the column looks like this 
12:40:39

12:40:39

12:40:39

12:40:39

Comment: What i have seen is that When searching for ' where ISDATE([TIME]) = 0' I copy the value in the table and past it into notepad++ and i see that the values have CR & LF which are new line chars but why doesnt it get replaced with my replace Query

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ISDATE` function to select corrupt data:

```
select * from #TEMP 
where ISDATE([TIME]) = 0
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx

> Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value;
>   otherwise, 0.

Comment: But, of course, that only does half the job because if the content of `TIME` can be successfully converted to a `date`, it's still going to cause an error when you try to change the column to be `time`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I get no errors: `CREATE TABLE #test(d VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2015-11-27 11:34:20.343')

ALTER TABLE #test ALTER COLUMN d TIME

SELECT * FROM #test`